# Is it possible to have multiple or "chained" field dependencies?

Tags: dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

For opportunities, we have a Type field with values Waste Water, Semiconductor and Industrial. We have a Stage field with values Budgetary and Quote/Proposal. We have a Probability field with values that range from 0% to 100%. We have a better history of success with different Types, so we'd like to connect the Probability to the Type, depending on the Stage.

For example, we'd like to make it so that if the Type is Waste Water and the Stage is Budgetary, then the Probability is 10%. But if the Type is Semiconductor and the Stage is Budgetary, then the Probability is 20%. If the Stage is Quote/Proposal and the Type is Industrial, then the Probability is 40%.

I've done field dependencies before, but only involving two fields. I can't seem to find a way to make a field dependent on the values in two other fields - it appears Salesforce will only allow a dependent field to have a single controlling field. Is there some other way to do this?

[image: Highlighted area show Type/Stage/Probability combinations]